# Problem with instances on curve

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have 4 objects (each as a linked .blend file) that I have running along a path in the sequence of blue, green, orange, red. As you can see, some of the objects are overlapping. How can I get them to not overlap and sequence properly?

[image]

Here's my geometry node:
[image]

Comment: Replace "Geometry to instance" by "Join Geometry" and use a random value as an input for the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your input mesh has overlapping vertices. Try merging them by distance, either in [edit mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/cleanup.html#merge-by-distance) or using the [Merge by Distance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/operations/merge_by_distance.html)-node directly in your node setup.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

just use this node setup:

[image]

So check "separate children" and use join geometry.